# How should I decide which flooring underlayment is best?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, underlayment

There's a few options of underlayment in local stores, fairly cheap and more expensive (based on cork, I guess). What are the differences, and what factors should I consider to make a choice? I'm planning to install laminate floor in a 2nd floor room, on the plywood subfloor.

Thanks!

Comment: What's on the first floor directly below that area?

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite broad, but there are two primary differences (aside from cost): sound management and the ability to level imperfect subfloors.

Sound management (deadening, which can reduce tapping noise) depends on the thickness and composition of the underlayment. Leveling ability is primarily a matter of underlayment thickness.

You'll need to discuss the options as they pertain to your choice of flooring and your subfloor situation with your sales pro and make a decision based on your personal criteria.